# Why do I keep my SSH connection, after suspending, if I have a window open on the server?

Tags: ssh, x11, ssh-tunneling, openssh, suspend

Every time when I'm connected to a remote machine using SSH and want to go away from my machine (for lunch, for example), I suspend it. When I type in the SSH console, it disconnects immediately, with the following message:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to [...] port 22: Broken pipe
```

Everything works fine, but, for example, if I open a window (say Firefox), it is redirecting the x11 to the client. When I suspend and come back, I don't see the message.

I'm using Linux Mint 19, using GNOME Terminal VTE 0.52.2 +GNUTLS -PCRE2, using OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017 on the client.  The server machine is running Debian 9, using OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u4, OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018.

Why would this be happening?